# Convert .Yaml to Java Classes Automatically On Application

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am using Maven with Java and have a .yaml file

```
data:
  users:
    id: "int"
    name: "string"
    email: "string"
    phone:
      - "string"
    address:
      line1: "string"
      line2: "string"
      zip: "int"
database:
  url: "any-dbs-url"
  username: "username"
  password: "password"
```

I want to be converted into a Java class when the application starts, this should be an automatic process, each time the application starts the classes should be created according to the changes in the .yaml file.

How can I achieve it? any suggestion, code or source would be very helpful.

I tried using snakeyaml dependency and created a class manually.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("file location\\yml-file-name.yml");

ManualClass manualClass = yaml.loadAs(inputStream,ManualClass.class);
System.out.println("manualClass = " + manualClass);
```

But manually creating classes for a lot of yaml files won't be feasible.

Comment: Can you say more about your application? Why do you have a lot of classes that you want to instantiate this way instead of just calling their constructors in your application?

Comment: You can try Jackson: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-yaml

Comment: @ndc85430 My application makes GET calls to some endpoints of another application, on receiving the response from another application I need to check if the data in that application has all the fields as mentioned in the .yaml and the type associated with it.

Comment: So your yaml act as a schema. Is your issue, that you got a to many different yamls or do they change during runtime (meaning you do not even know them during development)?

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you just have code to deserialise the responses, that would fail if some fields were missing? Why do you need the YAML in that case?